# "Sequent" vs "sequential"

Tags: word-meaning, difference

What's the difference between "sequent" and "sequential"? I think I know when to use "sequential", but I am not sure about "sequent" since I haven't found the usage of it in sentences.

Comment: Sequent is a very technical word (that I had to look up).  Is it possible you mean "sequence" instead?  It could be easy to confuse the two in spoken language.  Sequence being a far more common word.

Comment: "Sequence" is a noun. I am considering the adjective "sequent".

Comment: You'll have to explain every time what you mean by *sequent*.

Comment: I think you need to edit to show us how you propose to use _sequent_.

Answer (score 1):

A sequence is sequential. Each step in the sequence is sequent. However, "sequent" is very rare in usage (except in "subsequent"). I would not recommend trying to use it in conversation.

They are basically equivalent for all intents and purposes, besides the fact that no one uses "sequent". (my spell check is not even recognizing it as a word)

Comment: Let's say, some series of numbers is sequential. Then how about numbers which the series consists of? Can we say that the numbers are sequential? Can we use "sequential" with objects forming the sequence?

Comment: @Vova, yes. I think "sequential" can universally be used in lieu of "sequent". No counter examples come to mind.